# Puppeteer's Click API does not trigger on image map element

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, headless

### Puppeteer's Click API does not trigger on image map element.

I am using a puppeteer for scraping different e-commerce sites. Some e-commerce sites show a popup on page ready. I am trying to close that popup using click api by targeting element but somehow getting an error as "Node is either not visible or not an Html Element".
I have applied click on selectors:
`coords='715,5,798,74'`
`#monetate_lightbox_mask'`
`body>div>div:nth-child(1)`
`body>div:nth-child(1):div:nth-child(1)`
`URLs for scraping:`

https://www.hayneedle.com/product/humantouchijoymassageanywherecordlessportablemassager.cfm
https://www.hayneedle.com/product/napoleonfiberglowventedgaslogset.cfm
https://www.hayneedle.com/product/napoleonsquarepropanefirepittable1.cfm

Please suggest.
Regards,
Manjusha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use the following to wait for and click the close button:

```
const close_button = await page.waitForSelector( '[id$="ltBoxMap"] > [href="#close"]' );
await close_button.click();
```

But unfortunately, it appears that the website has implemented bot detection and is displaying the following page:

[image]

The source of the resulting web page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
        <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Access To Website Blocked</h1>

</body></html>
```

The bot detection service cannot be fooled simply by [changing the user agent](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetuseragentuseragent), so you will need to experiment with some other methods to bypass the service if you would like to scrape the website.

Comment: Thanks, I have used some proxy servers to resolve this issue.
Also, I have used steps to automate URLs and made code generic.